# How to disable Remember Me checkbox in AuthenticationContext Login Windows App?

Tags: c#, authentication, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, remember-me

I am using an authentication context in a windows 10 universal app. When I signed in the first time I checked Remember Me and now every time I sign out and try to login, it automatically logs me in without prompting. How do I disable it? You can get the same prompt with:

```
AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, clientId, redirectURI, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, false));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I'm silly, it's literally in the parameters:

```
new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, false);
```

to

```
new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always, false);
```